# Problem with WriteableBitmap on big images

Tags: c#, wpf

In the program, I need to quickly draw on the image. To do this, I chose WriteableBitmap, and I perform the necessary manipulations with BackBuffer. And everything is drawn safely, as long as the image size does not exceed a certain limit in the region of 1500 pixels. Above this size, instead of the desired shape, something else appears.

```
writeable.Lock();
IntPtr buff = writeable.BackBuffer;
unsafe
{
    byte* pbuff = (byte*)buff.ToPointer();
    ...
}
writeable.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, (int)writeable.Width, (int)writeable.Height));
writeable.Unlock();
```

[At the top of an incorrect result of drawing down approximately as it should look (round brush).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJObk.jpg)

If we do not update the entire image, but only the area you are changing, the result is identical to updating the entire image. What is the problem? Is this a feature of BackBuffer or some other restrictions on the size of WriteableBitmap? And what to do with it if we need very fast rendering on images of 15-30 megapixels? Please do not consider options with Direct2D.

Comment: I used WriteableBitmap for very large images 20 MP and bigger and had no problems. But maybe do not use (int)Width and (int)Height. WriteableBitmap has extra PixelWidth and PixelHeight Properties.

Comment: Could you please provide a code snippet of how you actually write to the buffer?

Comment: This can be seen in my answer below.

Comment: @Quergo By the way, do you have any feedback here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/61416524/1136211

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096979/writeablebitmap-access-violation-problem), I solved this problem by changing the way BackBuffer is accessed.

Code that doesn't work with big images:

```
writeable.Lock();
IntPtr buff = writeable.BackBuffer;
unsafe
{
    byte* pbuff = (byte*)buff.ToPointer();

    pbuff[Index * 3 + 0] = (byte)(B);
    pbuff[Index * 3 + 1] = (byte)(G);
    pbuff[Index * 3 + 2] = (byte)(R);
}
writeable.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, writeable.PixelWidth, writeable.PixelHeight));
writeable.Unlock();
```

Working code:

```
writeable.Lock();
unsafe
{
    long pBackBuffer = (long)writeable.BackBuffer;
    int stride = writeable.BackBufferStride;

    int offset = (int)(RelativeY * stride + RelativeX * 3);
    long pBackBufferWithOffset = pBackBuffer + offset;
    *((byte*)pBackBufferWithOffset + 0) = (byte)(B);
    *((byte*)pBackBufferWithOffset + 1) = (byte)(G);
    *((byte*)pBackBufferWithOffset + 2) = (byte)(R);
}
writeable.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, writeable.PixelWidth, writeable.PixelHeight));
writeable.Unlock();
```

writeable.**Pixel**Width OR (**int**)writeable.Width - doesn't matter.

It is important to use this - **long**, not this - **int**.

Comment: "*writeable.PixelWidth OR (int)writeable.Width - doesn't matter*" - only as long as it has exactly 96 DPI. If you deal with pixels, *always* use PixelWidth/-Height.